# Connect to remote server without SSH Key using VSCode and AWS SSM

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, visual-studio-code, ssm

I'm looking for a way to connect to a server with VSCode without an SSH key. One way is to enable password authentication which I'd rather avoid. The servers are on company LAN but I still don't want to go that route.

We've looked at solutions such as Okta ASA for keyless SSH connection (client/agent model). And also AWS SSM with IAM Roles and profiles. Both work great through Terminal, but not sure how that connection could be passed through an IDE such as when you use a key or password.

Any thoughts or directions would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: were you successful?